# Function not declared when using btoa for a simple encryption site

Tags: javascript, html, encoding

I am trying to make a simple encryption site to fiddle with b64 a little more

```
<html>
    <script language="javascript">
        function encrypt() {
            var texttoencrypt = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
            var encrypted = btoa(texttoencrypt)
            document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = encrypted;
        }
    </script>
    <head></head>
    <title>Base64 Encrypt</title>
    <body>
        <textarea id="text" rows="4" cols="50" autofocus placeholder="Put text here."></textarea>
        <br>
        <button onclick="encrypt()">Encrypt</button>
        <button onclick="decrypt()">Decrypt</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

The error it gives me is:

ReferenceError: encrypt is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

when I click encrypt.

Comment: Base64 is an encoding. It has nothing to do with encryption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `script` into a head section:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript">
            function encrypt() {
                var texttoencrypt = document.getElementById("text").value;
                var encrypted = btoa(texttoencrypt);
                document.getElementById("text").value = encrypted + ' - test';
            }
            function decrypt() {
                // ...
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <title>Base64 Encrypt</title>
    <body>
        <textarea id="text"
                  rows="4" cols="50"
                  autofocus placeholder="Put a text here">
        </textarea>
        <br>
        <button onclick="encrypt()">Encrypt</button>
        <button onclick="decrypt()">Decrypt</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Update: you need to use a value property `document.getElementById("text").value` when you want to get a text from `<textarea></textarea>`.

Comment: Thanks!! This worked for me, guess jsbin is a poorly made editor.

Comment: @Alex there is no need for JSFiddle nowadays on Stack Overflow. This functionality is already included. I was so free as to edit it into your answer.